# Два изображения в фоне одного элемента

Tags: css3, jquery, html, javascript

Имеем:

```
<div class="game">Chelsea VS PSG</div>
```

И стиль:

```
.game { background: url(../img/tms/chelsea.jpg) 100% 50% no-repeat, url(../img/tms/psg.jpg) 0% 50% no-repeat; }
```

Одно изображение накрывает другое. Как можно обрезать верхнее изображение (Челси) пополам? Тобишь вопрос сводится к тому, как средствами css сделать фон из половины изображения.

```
background-size: 50% 100%;
```

Показывает сразу 2 изображения, не обрезая.

Comment: мб проще использовать 2 дива внутри первого с отдельными фонами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Можно сделать с помощью псевдоэлементов](http://jsfiddle.net/536W2/)**

```
.game {
    height: 200px;
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
}
.game::after, .game::before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
.game::before {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/400x200/efaefa&text=CHELSEA') 0% 50% no-repeat;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.game::after {
    background: url('http://placehold.it/200/e22a2a&text=PSG') 0% 50% no-repeat;
    right: 0;
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: то что нужно, благодарю!